# Установка laravel в требуемую папку. Опции команды composer

Tags: php, windows, laravel, composer, установка

Я решил установить laravel в `D:\OpenServer\domains\myedica`. Я нашел следующую команду установки

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

В результате (см. скриншот) в папку myedica установилась папка laravel. Как установить laravel прямо в корень папки myedica (на уровень выше, чем сейчас)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `composer create-project laravel/laravel .` но директория при этом должна быть пустой.

Comment: _Как установить laravel прямо в корень папки myedica (на уровень выше, чем сейчас)?_ - ctrl+c => ctrl+v